# Trying to use JSONStore in a combo

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

In our application we have a lot of name/value stores, and they are created at load time and put into a **JSONStore** like so :

```
Ext.create("Ext.data.JsonStore", {
    data: data,
    model: 'EM.model.controlUnit.CodeList',
    storeId: "cl_" + tableId,
    sorters: [{
        sorterFn: aSorterFunction
    }],
});
```

The model is pretty simple and looks like this :

```
Ext.define('EM.model.controlUnit.CodeList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [{
        name: 'value', type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'label', type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'description', type: 'string'
    }]
});
```

I thought stores were pretty interchangeable so I decided to use the store in the combo (There is no special combo store so I thought a JSONStore must be as good as a **SimpleStore**). I get the store like so :

```
var msDataStore = Ext.getStore("cl_t_cl_maritalstatus");
```

And use the store like so :

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'Marital Status',
    displayField: "label",
    valueField: "value",
    store: msDataStore
}
```

The combo is filled with the values from the store when I run the application, however, when I pop down the combo box, this error is thrown :

> ext-debug-w-comments.js:9951 Uncaught
>   Ext.data.proxy.Server.buildUrl(): You are using a ServerProxy but have
>   not supplied it with a url.

I do not want any server proxy. These are simple locally stored name value collections.

- Can JSONStores be used with combos?
- If not. What is the best way to convert a JSONStore into something acceptable for the combo. I can chop, change, restructure the store object. But I just want to know if there is something simpler that I can do before going on some kind of long and pointless journey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JsonStore` without URL is completely acceptable, but you have to make sure the combo does not trigger a load operation when clicking on the dropdown. This is done by adding to the combo definition the config option [`queryMode:'local'`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-queryMode):

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'Marital Status',
    displayField: "label",
    valueField: "value",
    queryMode: 'local',
    store: msDataStore
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem is related 'proxy' property. Default proxy for JsonStore is 'ajax';

```
proxy: {
    type  : 'ajax',
    reader: 'json',
    writer: 'json'
}
```

You should override with 'memory' like that;

```
proxy: {
    type: 'memory'
}
```

Your final store is;

```js
Ext.create("Ext.data.JsonStore", {
    data: data,
    model: 'EM.model.controlUnit.CodeList',
    storeId: "cl_" + tableId,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory'
    }
    sorters: [{
        sorterFn: aSorterFunction
    }],
});
```